# Consider the equation $\,\,x^{2007}-1+x^{-2007}=0.\,$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck with the following problem:

> Consider the equation $\,\,x^{2007}-1+x^{-2007}=0.\,$Let $\,m$ be the number of distinct complex non-real roots and $\,n$ be the number of  distinct  real roots of the above equation. Then $\,m-n\,$ is
>
> 1.$\,0$
>
> 2.$\,2006$
>
> 3.$\,2007$
>
> 4.$\,4014$

Can someone explain? Thanks in advance for your time.

*My Attempt*: $y=x^{2007}$ gives $y^2-y+1=0 \implies y=\frac12 \pm \frac{\sqrt 3i}{2}.\,\,$Now, I am not sure how  to progress.

Comment: Hint: Consider the substitution $y=x^{2007}$. Do you still get stuck? If so, what steps have you tried?

Comment: They are asking how many solutions are there in the equation that are complex but not real.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

Putting $x^{2007}=a$ we get $a-1+\frac1a=0\iff a^2-a+1=0$

Observe that the discriminant of the last quadratic equation $<0$

Hence the values of $a$ are complex

As $x^{2007}(=a)$ is complex, so will be all the values of $x$

for  if $x$ is real, so will be $x^n$ for any integer $n$

Do you know the number of roots of $$x^{2007}-1+x^{-2007}=0$$

Comment: Yes .The total number of roots is $4014.$ as $$x^{2007}-1+x^{-2007}=0 \implies x^{4014}-x^{2007}+1=0.$$ Am I right?

Comment: @learner, so you are done

Comment: @learner, as  both the values of $a$ are complex, each value of $x$ corresponding to each complex $a$ must be complex, so there will be no real root

Comment: so,$m-n=4014-0=4014$ and I am done.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

let $A=x^{2007}\,\,\,\,$
new equation is $\,A^2+1=A $ that has no real root

Comment: Seeing your answers so far, why wouldn't you take a look on [this particular topic](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500/what-about-overview-of-basic-latex-commands-here-in-meta) to familiarize yourself with the mathematical formatting on this site. The fact of using an image done inside paint for an equation may result un-clear and time consuming (with all respect, don't get me wrong `:-)`.